# Absolute positioning behind non-absolute element

Tags: html, css, z-index, absolute

I have an element which contains two children, one of which is positioned absolutely. I would like this absolutely positioned element to be *behind* its sibling. It seems `z-index` does not have much of an effect. How do I accomplish this?

JSFiddle  here: http://jsfiddle.net/03c3qq6w/ I want the green box to be behind the red one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting **position: relative** to `#two` **div** fix the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/03c3qq6w/1/

```
#two {
    position: relative;
}
```

In order to use **z-index** you have to add **position** to your element.

**From Css-Tricks**:

> The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of
>   elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically
>   closer to you. z-index only effects elements that have a position
>   value other than static (the default).

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: I did not realize that default positioned elements could not have z-indexes. Thank you for that!